# Copy any replacements made in a macro to a separate file as a report, with page number

Tags: vba, ms-word

I am currently learning how to create macros in word to find errors such as spaces between words, after sentences, the code is widely available to do this and I have been using the code below to help identify any errors (i kinda mashed a few macros together, it's not flawless as they don't seem to interect well together, but this is not my question).

I am trying to find out how to display the page number of anything found in find and replace, and the snippet of text it wants to replace, in a report at the end of the document or ideally in a seperate blank one, in some kind of readable format, I cannot find any examples of this and wonder if it is possible? Thanks!

```
Option Explicit
Sub SpacingFixer()
 'If something goes wrong, go to the errorhandler
    On Error GoTo ERRORHANDLER
    'Current page variable
    CurPage = Selection.Information(wdActiveEndAdjustedPageNumber)
    'Checks the document for excessive spaces between words
    With Selection
        .HomeKey Unit:=wdStory
        With .Find
            .ClearFormatting
            .Replacement.ClearFormatting
            'Here is where it is actually looking for spaces between words
            .Text = " [ ]@([! ])"
            'This line tells it to replace the excessive spaces with one space
            .Replacement.Text = " \1"
            .MatchWildcards = True
            .Wrap = wdFindStop
            .Format = False
            .Forward = True
            'execute the replace
            .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
        End With
        
        ' Remove white space at the beginning of lines

    With Selection.Find

        .Text = "^p^w"

        .Replacement.Text = "^p"

    End With

Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll

' Removes spaces in first line

    With Selection.Find

        .Text = " {3,}"

        .Replacement.Text = ""

    End With

Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
         
        With .Find
            'This time its looking for excessive spaces after a paragraph mark
            .Text = "^p "
            'What to replace it with
            .Replacement.Text = "^p"
            .MatchWildcards = False
            .Wrap = wdFindStop
            .Format = False
            .Forward = True
            'Execute the replace
            .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
        End With
    End With
ERRORHANDLER:
    With Selection
        .ExtendMode = False
        .HomeKey Unit:=wdStory
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: The replace function is not going to be able to catch the page while it is happening. Keep in mind that pagination in Word is generally a slippery thing. See Word Doesn't Know What a Page Is by Daiya Mitchell https://wordmvp.com/Mac/PagesInWord.html --- I would first catch the page numbers where the found object appears, save that info and then do the replace. --- What have you done to create the report document? I would approach this by creating an array to store the term and the page number and then export that to a new document rather than flipping back and forth.

Comment: Thanks for the advice! I guess that is why there aren't many examples of macros like this. I will have a play around with it.

I will likely try using a script to open a new blank page at the end of the macro and print the array there when I can figure out how to grab the information.

Comment: On the contrary, there are *many* such macros on the web. For examples of macros that uses F/R to retrieve pages #s for specified content, see: https://www.msofficeforums.com/140662-post2.html; and https://www.msofficeforums.com/149178-post3.html. For your purposes, though, it might be best to do the F/R with track changes on. You then have the option of generating a report of the changes via either the original pagination or the revised pagination. See, for example: https://www.msofficeforums.com/133132-post2.html

Comment: Excellent, I'll research into it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can’t use a ReplaceAll because it won’t allow a pause to capture the page number of the replacement, I’ve modified your code to an iterating Find/Replace. I also changed it to use a Range versus Selection because it will reduce some of the lost speed by going from a ReplaceAll to the iteration method. And finally I added the capturing of the Section and Page numbers into a Text file that will be created in the same folder as the document.

Check it out and modify to your exact needs.

```
Sub SpacingFixer()
    Dim doc As Word.Document, rng As Word.Range
    Dim FileNum As Integer
    Dim oFile As String
    
    On Error GoTo ERRORHANDLER
    Set doc = ActiveDocument
    Set rng = doc.Content
    
    FileNum = FreeFile()
    oFile = doc.path & "\AuthorTec_Edits.txt"
    If Dir(oFile, vbNormal) <> vbNullString Then
        Kill oFile
    End If
    Open oFile For Append As #FileNum
    Print #FileNum, "Extra spaces between words on Section:Page:"
    With rng.Find
        .ClearFormatting
        .Replacement.ClearFormatting
        'Here is where it is actually looking for spaces between words
        .Text = " [ ]@([! ])"
        'This line tells it to replace the excessive spaces with one space
        .Replacement.Text = " \1"
        .MatchWildcards = True
        .Wrap = wdFindStop
        .Format = False
        .Forward = True
        'execute the replace
        While .Execute
           Print #FileNum, rng.Information(wdActiveEndSectionNumber) & ":" & rng.Information(wdActiveEndAdjustedPageNumber)
           rng.Collapse Word.WdCollapseDirection.wdCollapseEnd
        Wend
    End With
        
        ' Remove white space at the beginning of lines
    Print #FileNum, "Extra white space at beginning of lines on Section:Page:"
    Set rng = doc.Content
    With rng.Find
        .Text = "^p^w"
        .Replacement.Text = "^p"
        While .Execute
           Print #FileNum, rng.Information(wdActiveEndSectionNumber) & ":" & rng.Information(wdActiveEndAdjustedPageNumber)
           rng.Collapse Word.WdCollapseDirection.wdCollapseEnd
        Wend
    End With

' Removes spaces in first line
    Print #FileNum, "Removed spaces in first line on Section:Page:"
    Set rng = doc.Content
    With rng.Find
        .Text = " {3,}"
        .Replacement.Text = ""
        While .Execute
           Print #FileNum, rng.Information(wdActiveEndSectionNumber) & ":" & rng.Information(wdActiveEndAdjustedPageNumber)
           rng.Collapse Word.WdCollapseDirection.wdCollapseEnd
        Wend
    End With

    Print #FileNum, "Removed excessive spaces after a paragraph mark on Section:Page:"
    Set rng = doc.Content
    With rng.Find
        'This time its looking for excessive spaces after a paragraph mark
        .Text = "^p "
        'What to replace it with
        .Replacement.Text = "^p"
        .MatchWildcards = False
        .Wrap = wdFindStop
        .Format = False
        .Forward = True
        While .Execute
           Print #FileNum, rng.Information(wdActiveEndSectionNumber) & ":" & rng.Information(wdActiveEndAdjustedPageNumber)
           rng.Collapse Word.WdCollapseDirection.wdCollapseEnd
        Wend
    End With
ERRORHANDLER:
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        MsgBox Err.Number & vbCr & Err.Description, vbCritical
        Err.Clear
    Else
        MsgBox "Action Complete"
    End If
    If FileNum <> 0 Then Close #FileNum

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you! I will have a play around and post what I create back here for others.

Comment: This actually does everything I could ask for, and can be modified to support other types of find and replace functions! Everyone learning about macros has something to learn from this code!

Answer (score 0):

Added the option to detect Bullet 1 and 2 styles ending in full stops and print them to the text file.

Also discovered that if you create an endless loop it is because .Wrap needs to be = wdFindStop

```
.Wrap = wdFindStop
```

```
Sub Spacingandbulletfixerwithreport()
    Dim doc As Word.Document, rng As Word.Range
    Dim FileNum As Integer
    Dim oFile As String
    
    On Error GoTo ERRORHANDLER
    Set doc = ActiveDocument
    Set rng = doc.Content
    
    FileNum = FreeFile()
    oFile = doc.Path & "\AuthorTec_Edits.txt"
    If Dir(oFile, vbNormal) <> vbNullString Then
        Kill oFile
    End If
    Open oFile For Append As #FileNum
    Print #FileNum, "Extra spaces between words on Section:Page:"
    With rng.Find
        .ClearFormatting
        .Replacement.ClearFormatting
        'Here is where it is actually looking for spaces between words
        .Text = " [ ]@([! ])"
        'This line tells it to replace the excessive spaces with one space
        .Replacement.Text = " \1"
        .MatchWildcards = True
        .Wrap = wdFindStop
        .Format = False
        .Forward = True
        'execute the replace
        While .Execute
           Print #FileNum, rng.Information(wdActiveEndSectionNumber) & ":" & rng.Information(wdActiveEndAdjustedPageNumber)
           rng.Collapse Word.WdCollapseDirection.wdCollapseEnd
        Wend
    End With
        
        ' Remove white space at the beginning of lines
    Print #FileNum, "Extra white space at beginning of lines on Section:Page:"
    Set rng = doc.Content
    With rng.Find
        .Text = "^p^w"
        .Replacement.Text = "^p"
        While .Execute
           Print #FileNum, rng.Information(wdActiveEndSectionNumber) & ":" & rng.Information(wdActiveEndAdjustedPageNumber)
           rng.Collapse Word.WdCollapseDirection.wdCollapseEnd
        Wend
    End With

' Removes spaces in first line
    Print #FileNum, "Removed spaces in first line on Section:Page:"
    Set rng = doc.Content
    With rng.Find
        .Text = " {3,}"
        .Replacement.Text = ""
        While .Execute
           Print #FileNum, rng.Information(wdActiveEndSectionNumber) & ":" & rng.Information(wdActiveEndAdjustedPageNumber)
           rng.Collapse Word.WdCollapseDirection.wdCollapseEnd
        Wend
    End With

    Print #FileNum, "Removed excessive spaces after a paragraph mark on Section:Page:"
    Set rng = doc.Content
    With rng.Find
        'This time its looking for excessive spaces after a paragraph mark
        .Text = "^p "
        'What to replace it with
        .Replacement.Text = "^p"
        .MatchWildcards = False
        .Wrap = wdFindStop
        .Format = False
        .Forward = True
        While .Execute
           Print #FileNum, rng.Information(wdActiveEndSectionNumber) & ":" & rng.Information(wdActiveEndAdjustedPageNumber)
           rng.Collapse Word.WdCollapseDirection.wdCollapseEnd
        Wend
    End With
    
    'search for bullet1s with full stops
    Print #FileNum, "Removed Bullet 1s on Section:Page:"
    Set rng = doc.Content
    With rng.Find
        .ClearFormatting
        .Style = ActiveDocument.Styles("Bullet 1")
        .Replacement.ClearFormatting
        .Text = ".^p"
        .Replacement.Text = ".^p"
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindStop
        .Format = True
        .MatchCase = False
        .MatchWholeWord = False
        .MatchWildcards = False
        .MatchSoundsLike = False
        .MatchAllWordForms = False
        While .Execute
           Print #FileNum, rng.Information(wdActiveEndSectionNumber) & ":" & rng.Information(wdActiveEndAdjustedPageNumber)
           rng.Collapse Word.WdCollapseDirection.wdCollapseEnd
           Wend
        End With
           
               'search for bullet2s with full stops
    Print #FileNum, "Removed Bullet 2s on Section:Page:"
    Set rng = doc.Content
    With rng.Find
        .ClearFormatting
        .Style = ActiveDocument.Styles("Bullet 2")
        .Replacement.ClearFormatting
        .Text = ".^p"
        .Replacement.Text = ".^p"
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindStop
        .Format = True
        .MatchCase = False
        .MatchWholeWord = False
        .MatchWildcards = False
        .MatchSoundsLike = False
        .MatchAllWordForms = False
        While .Execute
           Print #FileNum, rng.Information(wdActiveEndSectionNumber) & ":" & rng.Information(wdActiveEndAdjustedPageNumber)
           rng.Collapse Word.WdCollapseDirection.wdCollapseEnd
        Wend
    End With
    
    

ERRORHANDLER:
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        MsgBox Err.Number & vbCr & Err.Description, vbCritical
        Err.Clear
    Else
        MsgBox "Action Complete"
    End If
    If FileNum <> 0 Then Close #FileNum

End Sub
```